# Call javascript method with anonymous asynchronous method in Objective C

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I want to call a javascript method from objective c which will return some data. I know how to call a simple method using JSContext. But the problem is that this method is downloading a file via XmlHttpRequest asynchronous call. I want to access that downloaded data variable but which will be available after some time. How can I achieve this. For example:

```
    function download(path)
{
    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    //asynchronous method call
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var file = new Uint8Array(xhr.response || xhr.mozResponseArrayBuffer);

        var downloaded = populateImageData(file);
        //Want to access this variable in objective-c
        return downloaded.toString();
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

How can I access downloaded variable in objective c

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I changed this line:

```
xhr.open("GET", path, true);
```

to this:

```
xhr.open("GET", path, false);
```

Now it will download the file synchronously.